# How to overlap top div tags in css

Tags: html, css, overlapping

Can someone please explain to me how I can accomplish the following effect in CSS. I need a div on the bottom and two divs overlapping it on top as the image illustrates below.

[image]

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Do you have a working sample of HTML/CSS we can take a look at to help adjust what you're doing?

Comment: SO is more for issue with code you wrote than a platform to provide code based on features needed. That said have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/jz6w10a1/ as it should point you in the right direction :)

Comment: Do you want Div#1 and Div#2 to consume the space within the div or do you want the divs to be outside  ??

Comment: Thanks everybody, I don't have a working code. I just wanted a few examples of how something like this could be done. I can take your guy's code and study it then I'll use it to create my own with the dimension needed for my project.. Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is to adjust the top margin of the smaller divs. Setting it to a negative value will pull them over the larger one. See code below.

Alternatively, you could wrap the smaller divs in a larger one and adjust the bottom margin to pull them down below.

```css
.under {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #3C77D4;
}

.over{
  background-color: #0E49AC;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 23px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="under"></div>
<div class="over"></div>
<div class="over"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the comment of @Liquidchrome statens there are many ways:

spencerlarry posted one possible way, here is another, it is just usefull if you have defined width which might even be calculated by you

here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="topPane">
      <div class="overlappingPane">

      </div>
      <div class="overlappingPane">

      </div>
      <div class="clearPane">

      </div>
   </div>
</div>



.container{
  display:inline-block;
}

.topPane{
  width:270px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  background-color:red;
}

.overlappingPane{
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
  width: 90px;
  height:90px;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  border: 2px black solid;
}

.clearPane{
  clear:both;
}
```

and here the Link to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/npnz85x0/